# Check upload file size before actual file data uploading

Tags: web2py

In my web2py controller I'm accessing file data like:

```
vfile = request.post_vars.video.file
```

But how can I check `Content-Length` *before* actual file data will be uploaded?
It is not a good idea for me to check file size after file already uploaded.

NOTE:
I'm not using `FORM()` helper and database but just raw regular file upload.
Is there any way to hook into web2py internals to do what I need?

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that you would have to detect it in the browser and pass it to web2py.
This is how I handled it server side. I know that you asked for the size before uploading but I figured this might be helpful anyway.

```
#insert file in db
image = db.image.file.store(request.vars["files[]"].file, request.vars["files[]"].filename)
id = db.image.insert(file=image,title=request.vars["files[]"].filename)
#get filename in db
record = db.image[id]
#find size
path_list = []
path_list.append(request.folder)
path_list.append('uploads')
path_list.append(record['file'])
print os.path.getsize(os.path.join(*path_list))
```